# Subfolders flattened in PyInstaller add-data

Tags: python, pyinstaller, packaging

I'm attempting to include a directory in my PyInstaller Python application using `--add-data="path/to/s1/*"`

This particular sub folder is structured like:

```
|...
|----/s1
|----|----/database
|----|----|----add.py
|----|----|----remove.py
|----|----/plot
|----|----|----bar_chart.py
|----|----|----pie_chart.py
|...
```

However, when doing this my subfolder structure is lost! `database` and `plot` are no longer subfolders of s1. The structure is flattened to root and all folders are stored together.

**Is there any way to maintain my original sub folder structure without having to reorganize my entire Python project?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was actually able to achieve my desired output by just copying the original file structure from my `src/` folder into my `dist/` directory after building.

Could be a flawed solution, but I haven't discovered any issues with it so far...

Answer (score 0):

I find PyInstaller will only flatten one layer of folders, while keeping the folder tree underlying that layer. In your case, just add another layer on top of it will work.

`--add-data="path/to/top_layer/*"`

The 'new_layer' will be flatten. But 's1' will be kept.

```
|-/top_layer
|--/new_layer
|----/s1
|----|----/database
|----|----|----add.py
|----|----|----remove.py
|----|----/plot
|----|----|----bar_chart.py
|----|----|----pie_chart.py
|...
```